How to run specific test commands for aarch64 linux platforms with python cibuildwheel
how to run specific test commands for aarch64 linux platforms with cibuildwheel
I'm working on a project as a contributor and I need to run specific tests on the Linux aarch platform during the execution of the release build. I'm currently running tests with the stestr run command and I can change this part of the pyproject.toml file:
[tool.cibuildwheel]
manylinux-x86_64-image = "manylinux2014"
manylinux-i686-image = "manylinux2014"
skip = "pp* cp36-* cp37-* *musllinux* *win32 *i686"
test-skip = "*win32 *linux_i686"
test-command = "stestr run"
before-test = "pip install --only-binary=numpy,scipy numpy scipy"
environment = 'RUSTUP_TOOLCHAIN="stable"'

[tool.cibuildwheel.linux]
before-all = "yum install -y wget && {package}/tools/install_rust.sh"
environment = 'PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.cargo/bin" CARGO_NET_GIT_FETCH_WITH_CLI="true" RUSTUP_TOOLCHAIN="stable"'
repair-wheel-command = "auditwheel repair -w {dest_dir} {wheel} && pipx run abi3audit --strict --report {wheel}"

[tool.cibuildwheel.macos]
environment = "MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.12"
repair-wheel-command = "delocate-wheel --require-archs {delocate_archs} -w {dest_dir} -v {wheel} && pipx run abi3audit --strict --report {wheel}"

[tool.cibuildwheel.windows]
repair-wheel-command = "cp {wheel} {dest_dir}/. && pipx run abi3audit --strict --report {wheel}"

I thought about adding a new section for Linux aarch64 like this:
# New command session for Linux aarch64
[tool.cibuildwheel.linux.aarch64]
test-command = "stestr run tests/linux_aarch64/"
before-all = "yum install -y wget && {package}/tools/install_rust.sh"
environment = 'PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.cargo/bin" CARGO_NET_GIT_FETCH_WITH_CLI="true" RUSTUP_TOOLCHAIN="stable"'
repair-wheel-command = "auditwheel repair -w {dest_dir} {wheel} && pipx run abi3audit --strict --report {wheel}"

Would anyone know if this approach is correct? I tried to run on Windowns with the cibuildwheel command, but i don't know how to test how it would happen on a Linux Aarch64, i need to know how to create a section for specific test commands for the Linux Aarch64 platform. Any help would be welcome. Thank you in advance for your attention.
